# Create a for loop that is consistent in php

Tags: php

I Have a for loop that i have been trying to work with to achieve a given goal, The loop should increment only the Y parameter for every time it runs, when i do a dry code for the same thing it works but if i try a loop everything becomes misaligned

Here is the hard coded sample

```
         //   for($s=0; $s<count($standards);$s++){

            $pdf->SetXY(32, 132);
            $pdf->Write(1, $standards[0]->name);

            $pdf->SetXY(106, 132);
            $pdf->Write(1, $standards[0]->rs_code);

            $pdf->SetXY(153, 132);
            $pdf->Write(1, round($standards[0]->potency,2));

             $pdf->SetXY(32, 139);
            $pdf->Write(1, $standards[1]->name);

            $pdf->SetXY(106, 139);
            $pdf->Write(1, $standards[1]->rs_code);

            $pdf->SetXY(153, 139);
            $pdf->Write(1, round($standards[1]->potency,2));

           // }
```

Now the dynamic for loop, I want that if the first Y values for the three XYs is 132, on the next run it should be 132+7, and continue incrementing like that for all loop runs, the below is returning data but misaligned as compared to the static one above

```
         $ya=(int)132;

           for($s=0; $s<count($standards);$s++){

            $pdf->SetXY(32, $ya+=7);
            $pdf->Write(1, $standards[$s]->name);

            $pdf->SetXY(106, $ya+=7);
            $pdf->Write(1, $standards[$s]->rs_code);

            $pdf->SetXY(153, $ya+=7);
            $pdf->Write(1, round($standards[$s]->potency,2));

             $pdf->SetXY(32, $ya+=7);
            $pdf->Write(1, $standards[$s]->name);

            $pdf->SetXY(106, $ya+=7);
            $pdf->Write(1, $standards[$s]->rs_code);

            $pdf->SetXY(153, $ya+=7);
            $pdf->Write(1, round($standards[$s]->potency,2));

            }
```

the result should be something like

```
 A      B     C
 D      E     F
```

and not

```
  A 
           B    
                  C

  D     
           E   
                   F
```

Comment: You only need the fourth `$ya+=7`, the rest should be just `$ya` as you only want to increment it once. Or perhaps the first and fourth when you start at `125` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. You need to increment it just once. That too after printing first three statements.

```
       $ya=(int)132;

       for($s=0; $s<count($standards);$s++){

        $pdf->SetXY(32, $ya);
        $pdf->Write(1, $standards[$s]->name);

        $pdf->SetXY(106, $ya);
        $pdf->Write(1, $standards[$s]->rs_code);

        $pdf->SetXY(153, $ya);
        $pdf->Write(1, round($standards[$s]->potency,2));

         $pdf->SetXY(32, $ya+=7);
        $pdf->Write(1, $standards[$s]->name);

        $pdf->SetXY(106, $ya);
        $pdf->Write(1, $standards[$s]->rs_code);

        $pdf->SetXY(153, $ya);
        $pdf->Write(1, round($standards[$s]->potency,2));

        }
```